# Can not get Metadata from s3 object

Tags: amazon-s3

I uploaded manually file to S3, added Metadata `x-amz-meta-alt-name` to this object.

Using AWS Javascript SDK I tried to get Metadata but got an empty object.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: "mybucket",
    Key: "myfile.txt"
};
s3.headObject(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.Metadata['x-amz-meta-alt-name']);
});
```

Output:
`undefined`

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Maybe I need to configure some policies.

Comment: What does debugging of data.Metadata say ?

Comment: Isn't it a header value ?

Comment: @SimonFranzen data.Metadata returns empty object

Comment: I just found that metadata presents in HTTP response, but I can't get it in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to expose the value in CORS settings like this

```
<CORSRule> 
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin> 
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod> 
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-description</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

But I am not sure if you can get these values in the callback.

This thread will help you understanding what is possible and what not https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/232